# Homestead folder won't update the mounted folder with my files

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

Everything seems to work on my windows 10 box as I try to set it up and I can access it through http://127.0.0.1:8000 but not http://Homestead.app Also the biggest issue is not being able to access my files through the mounted folder. I have changed the file paths to forward slashes instead of backslashes on the paths but I can't access the files of my app.

```
==> homestead-7: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> homestead-7: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> homestead-7: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> homestead-7: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    homestead-7: Adapter 1: nat
    homestead-7: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> homestead-7: Forwarding ports...
    homestead-7: 80 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 443 (guest) => 44300 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 3306 (guest) => 33060 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 5432 (guest) => 54320 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 8025 (guest) => 8025 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 27017 (guest) => 27017 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> homestead-7: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> homestead-7: Booting VM...
==> homestead-7: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    homestead-7: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    homestead-7: SSH username: vagrant
    homestead-7: SSH auth method: private key
==> homestead-7: Machine booted and ready!
==> homestead-7: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> homestead-7: Setting hostname...
==> homestead-7: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> homestead-7: Mounting shared folders...
    homestead-7: /vagrant => C:/Users/mattr/boxes/Homestead
==> homestead-7: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> homestead-7: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.
```

My CLI results from bringing up the vagrant box.

and my Homestead.yaml is

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: C:/Users/mattr/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - C:/Users/mattr/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Code/test/
      to: C:/Users/mattr/Projects/home_lara/

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/test/public/

databases:
    - homestead

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

Thanks if you can help me I really appreciate it as it. If I am lacking in any details comment I'll be quick to grab them.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to access your app via `homestead.app` you have to add it to your host file which is located in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` just edit it and add the line :

```
192.168.10.10    homestead.app
```

And in order to save the modifications you made on the homestead.yaml file try to 
run the command `vargant reload --provision`.

Oh and I just saw that in the folders part you inverted the links you should map the folder of your project to /home/vagrant/code to tell the server that the code foler will point to your project folder like this :

```
folders:
    - map: C:\Users\mattr\Projects\home_lara
      to: /home/vagrant/code
```